# Firefox CSS image box

Tags: css, firefox

This CSS code does work in all browsers except FireFox. Why ? How can I fix it ?

```
.img_box {
  width: 110px;
  height: 160px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Here is the HTML that I want to use:

```
<img class="img_box" />
```

Comment: The works / doesn't work dichotomy is not mutually exhaustive.  So, I'll answer "yes."

Comment: What doesn't work? The height? The width? The background image? Specifics man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Firefox encounters an image without a source, it replaces the image with its alt text. I personally find this extremely annoying, as it means I can't test layouts unless I specifically create placeholder images, and should those images be unavailable for any reason the layout completely breaks.

Unfortunately, I have yet to find a solution to this problem.

In your case, however, you would be much better off using a `div` and adding `display:inline-block` to your CSS, instead of using an image.

Comment: The reason Firefox does this is so that the user can actually read the alt text (something other browsers make extremely difficult).  That's the case Firefox is aiming to get right; testing with images with no src is an edge case.  And of course if a layout breaks if an image is not available it'll also break if the user has images turned off, so it's just sort of broken to start with.  That said you can style your "just testing" images with `-moz-force-broken-image-icon: 1` to force them to be rendered with a sized box even if there's no actual image to show.

Comment: Erm... so when the browser shows the broken image with the alt text next to the icon, that's not readable? I guess not on small images, but still...

Comment: Precisely.  For the vast majority of small or medium sized images, the alt text, if written properly, is far too long to actually be readable in the small sized box most UAs show....

Answer (score 0):

**solution1:**

```
.img_box {
  width: 110px;
  height: 160px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png');
  display: block;
}
```

**solution2:**

```
<div class="img_box"></div>
```